# Vaadin too many logs :INFO [v-server-output] DevServerOutputTracker : [TypeScript] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin8

I downloaded a Vaadin starter project from [Vaadin Starter](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/overview) and running in my eclipse. It is giving me continuous logs. Can someone tell me the reason of these logs and how can I suppress these logs?

```
2023-01-08 13:43:00.370  INFO 16860 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 
2023-01-08 13:43:00.370  INFO 16860 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : [TypeScript] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
2023-01-08 13:43:00.945  INFO 16860 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 
2023-01-08 13:43:00.945  INFO 16860 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : [TypeScript] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

Comment: As in you "do nothing" and this repeats ad infinitum roughly every half
second?  Does it also happen outside eclipse?

Comment: Hi @cfrick - Yes the message is coming in every half second. It makes it difficult to find my actual logs. I have not tried outside the eclipse. I tried some older version of Vaadin which is not giving this log so frequently